# Cascading deletes in mutually dependent tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, cascade, sql-delete

I have a situation where two of my database tables have foreign keys pointing at each other. This is through MySQL via SQLAlchemy. I want to make it so that when I delete the parent, all child rows are deleted. My schema (simplified) looks like this:

```
Parent(id, child_id, another_child_id)

Child(id, parent_id)
```

I have set `ondelete='CASCADE'` on the Parent relationship in the Child model definition.

According to [this section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#rows-that-point-to-themselves-mutually-dependent-rows) on the SQLAlchemy docs, all you need to do is set `post-update` and this will supposedly handle deleting the children for you without running into key constraint errors.

Unfortunately, I think my situation is odd in that I have two columns in Parent that point to the Child, which is different from the example in the docs. The following relationship configuration in Parent gives me a foreign key constraint error when I try to delete the parent (since `parent_id` depends on the parent existing):

```
child = relationship('Child', 
    primaryjoin='Child.id==Article.child_id',
    post_update=True)
another_child = relationship('Child', 
    primaryjoin='Child.id==Article.another_child_id',
    post_update=True)
```

The only way I could get it working was to put a `cascade='delete'` flag on either one of the columns:

```
child = relationship('Child', 
    primaryjoin='Child.id==Article.child_id',
    post_update=True,
    cascade='delete')
another_child = relationship('Child', 
    primaryjoin='Child.id==Article.another_child_id',
    post_update=True)
```

The odd thing is that when I put `cascade='delete'` on both columns, then all sorts of problems occur. For example:

```
c = Child()
p = Parent()
p.child = c
p.another_child = c
session.add(p)
session.commit()
```

The above code will create a Parent in the database but the `child_id` and `another_child_id` columns are NULL. The child row is never even created.

Can anyone explain why `cascade='delete'` is able to solve my problem of cascading deletes to the children instead of just having `ondelete='CASCADE'` on the child foreign key? Also why does it only work when it is set on one of the relationships rather than both (which seems more logicical to me)?