# SQLalchemy mutually dependent foreign key constraints

Tags: sqlalchemy

I’m trying to define 2 entities like this:

```py
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(256), index=True, unique=True)
    main_token_id = Column(ForeignKey('token.id'), nullable=False)

    main_token = relationship('Token', uselist=False)
    tokens = relationship('Token', back_populates="user", foreign_keys=['token.id'])


class Token(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    user: User = relationship("user", back_populates="tokens")
```

I want the user to have access to the collection of all his tokens and I also want him to have a special, main token. I want to ensure that the user has just one main token and I need integrity provided by the foreign key. By both of them actually.

I have read [Cascading deletes in mutually dependent tables in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977790/cascading-deletes-in-mutually-dependent-tables-in-sqlalchemy) but I don't feel it helps. I would like to have the integrity from both sides.

How can I make this work? If the design is flawed how can I rephrase this so that I may keep my integrity guarantees?

Comment: The sqlalchemy examples have foreign key constraints but it seems that main_token could be left null.  Is that the situation you are concerned with?  Ie. If tokens exist then a main token must exist?  Or can tokens exist without a main token?

Comment: I am interested in having the guarantee that once a user exists there exists atleast one token that is supposed to be the main one and I want to have integrity constraints on this relation guaranteeing that when the user is deleted, then the main token (specified by main_token_id) is also deleted. The user may have additional tokens also. I am not bothered if the tokens relation also includes the main token but I also want integrity constraints on this and by that I mean that when the user is deleted, all the user's tokens should also be deleted

Answer (score 0):

A kludge I have used to sort of solve this problem before is to create a column like `precedence = Column(Integer, nullable=False)` on tokens.  Then set a unique constraint like `UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'precedence')`. Then set that integer manually when you create the tokens.  The token with precedence 0 or the lowest precedence is the *main token*.

Here is an example.  I'm sure some sqlalchemy geniuses can perform the precedence swap without 3 updates but I think in most cases that doesn't come up very often.  There is a way to defer the unique constraint within a transaction but I guess sqlite does not support that yet.

This relies on your application not clearing the main token from precedence 0, ie. no integrity check to prevent that.

```py
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    UnicodeText,
    Integer,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
    UniqueConstraint,
    update,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Table,
    Column,
    MetaData,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError


Base = declarative_base()


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(256), index=True, unique=True)
    tokens = relationship('Token', backref="user", cascade="all, delete-orphan", order_by='Token.precedence')

    main_token = relationship('Token', primaryjoin='and_(User.id == Token.user_id, Token.precedence == 0)', viewonly=True, uselist=False)


class Token(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tokens'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    precedence = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('precedence', 'user_id', name='tokens_user_precedence'),)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session:
    user = User(name='tokenizer')
    session.add(user)
    main_token = Token(user=user, precedence=0)
    session.add(main_token)
    session.add(Token(user=user, precedence=1))
    session.commit()
    assert session.query(Token).first()
    assert session.query(User).first()
    assert session.query(User).first().tokens
    assert session.query(User).first().tokens[0] == main_token
    # This viewonly relationship seems to be working.
    assert session.query(User).first().main_token == main_token

    # We don't want this so don't do this, no integrity checks here!!
    main_token.precedence = 100
    session.commit()
    assert not session.query(User).first().main_token

    # Put it back now.
    main_token.precedence = 0
    session.commit()
    assert session.query(User).first().main_token

    # Now check tokens are cleared.
    session.delete(user)
    session.commit()
    assert not session.query(Token).all()
    assert not session.query(User).all()


with Session(engine) as session:
    # Try making 2 main tokens.
    user = User(name='tokenizer')
    session.add(user)
    main_token = Token(user=user, precedence=0)
    main_token2 = Token(user=user, precedence=0)
    session.add_all([main_token, main_token2])
    try:
        session.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        pass
    else:
        assert False, 'Exception should have occurred.'

with Session(engine) as session:
    # Try swapping the tokens.
    user = User(name='tokenizer')
    session.add(user)
    main_token = Token(user=user, precedence=0)
    session.add(main_token)
    other_token = Token(user=user, precedence=1)
    session.add(other_token)
    session.commit()
    old_precedence = other_token.precedence
    main_token.precedence = -1
    session.flush()
    other_token.precedence = 0
    session.flush()
    main_token.precedence = old_precedence
    session.commit()
    user.tokens[0] == other_token
    user.tokens[1] == main_token
    user.main_token == other_token
    session.commit()
```